# Modify the start and end index of a function involving RuleDelayed

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, rule

I have a list $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$ and an array of variables $\{y[1],y[2],y[3],y[4],y[5],y[6]\}$. I want to use the `RuleDelayed` function represented by the symbol `:>` to replace the variables with the elements on the list $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$. The code is written as,

```
list={a,b,c,d,e,f};
array=Array[y, 6];
array/.y[i_] :> list[[i]]
```

However, I want the `RuleDelayed` function `:>` to replace $\{y[2],y[3],y[4],y[5]\}$ with $b,c,d,e$ excluding the first and last terms so that I have `{y[2]:>b,y[3]:>c,y[4]:>d,y[5]:>e}`, i.e., the function `y[i_]` starts from `i=2` and ends at `i=5`. The question is, how should I modify the function `y[i_] :> list[[i]]` so that the index starts at `i=2` and ends at `i=5`?

Please do not respond by saying that I should just generate an array from `y[2]` to `y[5]`. I asked this question while using `RuleDelayed` to understand how to modify the function `y[i_]`.

Comment: `list = {b, c, d, e}; array /. y[i_ /; 1 < i < 6] :> list[[i - 1]]`

Comment: "...modify the function `y[i_]`", does this mean you actually want to set DownValues for y? I.e. you want to end up with definitions like `y[2]=a` and so forth?

Comment: Do you need it to work for arbitrary sized lists? Like for any given length for `array` and `list` do you want the rule to always be "centered"?

Comment: Just for clarity’s sake, with OP’s second list example, `list[[2]]` would give `c`, rather than `b`, as it seems to be implied by OP. Unless, of course, the second list example is being compared with the first, in some way? This needs more information, to be sure.

Comment: @lericr `DownValues`? I guess not. Yes, I want it for arbitrary sized list and basically, if you give me a list of length `n`. I want to replace `{y[2], ..., y[n-1]}` with it, i.e., the array of `y` starts at `i=2` and ends at `i=n-1`. However, I want to do this using `RuleDelayed`.

Comment: @CATrevillian The list in the paragraph before my code is to show how `RuleDelayed` works basically. However, if I'm to use `RuleDelayed` but I want the array `y` to start from `i=2` and end at `i=n-1` where `n` is the array length and `y[2]` gets assigned to `b` from the list `{a, b, c, d, e, f}` and `y[n-1] = y[5]` gets assigned to `e` from the list `{a, b, c, d, e, f}` as well, I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Are you looking for something as simple as `array /. y[i_] :> If[Length[array] > i > 1, list[[i]], y[i]]`?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Almost, but without the first and last element. The function should give the assignment only to the second until to the second to the last element (which your code does as well as the first commenter) and gives the result without the first and last, `y[1]` and `y[n]`. I know I may just use `Part` or `Take` but will that influence the speed when I apply this to a large set of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array /. y[i_] :> If[Length[array] > i > 1, list[[i]], Nothing]
(* {b, c, d, e} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may create a table of rules that depend on the length of list. If the length is 6 we would have: y[1]:>list[[1],.. however if the list starts with b, we would have: y[2]->b,..:

```
list = {a . b, c, d, e, f};
rules = Thread[
  Array[y[# - Length[list] + 6] &, Length[list]] -> list]
array /. rules
(* {a, b, c, d, e, f} *)
```

However with a shorter list:

```
list = {b, c, d, e, f};
rules = Thread[
  Array[y[# - Length[list] + 6] &, Length[list]] -> list]
array /. rules
(* y[1], b, c, d, e, f} *)

list = {c, d, e, f};
rules = Thread[
  Array[y[# - Length[list] + 6] &, Length[list]] -> list]
array /. rules
(* {y[1], y[2], c, d, e, f} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm interpreting the question as asking how to generate the replacement rule and not actually doing the replacement. I'm also interpreting the comment about not generating the array to mean that we don't want any sort of "threaded" structure, but an indexed-based rule. And finally, the OP indicated in a comment that it should work for arbitrarily sized lists. Here's a function that might work:

```
CenteredRule[fn_Symbol, fnLength_Integer?Positive, vals_List] :=
  With[
    {offset = Floor[(fnLength - Length@vals)/2]},
    fn[i_Integer] :> vals[[i - offset]] /; offset < i <= offset + Length@vals]
```

Examples:

```
CenteredRule[y, 6, {b, c, d, e}]
```

`y[i$_] :> {b, c, d, e}[[i$ - 1]] /; 1 < i$ <= 1 + Length[{b, c, d, e}]`

```
CenteredRule[y, 4, {a, b, c, d, e, f}]
```

`y[i$_] :> {a, b, c, d, e, f}[[i$ - -1]] /; -1 < i$ <= -1 + Length[{a, b, c, d, e, f}]`

Applications:

```
Array[z, 7] /. CenteredRule[z, 7, {b, c, d, e}]
```

`{z[1], b, c, d, e, z[6], z[7]}`

```
Array[w, 4] /. CenteredRule[w, 4, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}]
```

`{c, d, e, f}`

```
Array[q, 9, {-2, 6}] /. CenteredRule[q, 3, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}]
```

`{q[-2], a, b, c, d, e, f, g, q[6]}`

```
Array[q, 9, {1, 5}] /. CenteredRule[q, 5, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}]
```

`{b, q[3/2], c, q[5/2], d, q[7/2], e, q[9/2], f}`

```
Array[q, 9, {1, 5}] /. CenteredRule[q, 5, {a, b, c}]
```

`{q[1], q[3/2], a, q[5/2], b, q[7/2], c, q[9/2], q[5]}`